# Multiple WordPress Installs in on Same Domain with Redirect Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a client with multiple WordPress installs on their domain. One in the root and several in sub-folders. They have been running into redirect issues.

The problem we have been running into is as follows:
Occasionally a user will type in: [domainname.com/sub-folder-1](http://domainname.com/sub-folder-1) (without the trailing slash) and the site will redirect to [domainname.comsub-folder-1](http://domainname.comsub-folder-1) removing the forward slash for the sub-folder.

Root .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub-folder-1$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub-folder-1/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub-folder-2$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub-folder-2/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub-folder-3$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sub-folder-3/.*$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Sub-Folder .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-folder-1
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Anyone have any idea's on how to stop this from happening? Also, I realize that a WordPress multisite installation would fix all these issues, but due to the size and complexity of the sites migrating them over is out of the question.

--

Update: The issue comes in when you call the url from http and it tries to force https. So, http://domainname.com/sub-folder-1 becomes https://www.domainname.comsub-folder-1.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had nothing to do with WordPress or the `.htaccess` file.

The httpd.conf file before

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com

    Redirect / https://www.domainname.com
</virtualhost>
```

The httpd.conf file now

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias www.domainname.com

    Redirect / https://domainname.com/
</virtualhost>
```

I guess the redirect needs the trailing forward slash in order to redirect inside of sub-directories properly.